# How to databind textbox based on listview selection

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datatable

I'm trying to bind my textbox to the datatable row based on the listbox selection.

```
public Edit(MovieSetSource movieSource)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = movieSource.GetMovies().Tables["Movie"];
        movieListBox.DataSource = bindingSource;
        movieListBox.ValueMember = "Name";

        nameText.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", movieListBox, "SelectedItem.Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
        producerText.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", movieListBox, "SelectedItem.Producer", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
        releaseYearText.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", movieListBox, "SelectedItem.Release Year", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    }
```

This is how I bind the movie.

The MovieSetSource class is here:

```
public class MovieSetSource : ISource
{

    private DataSet _movieSet;
    private SqlDataAdapter _movieAdapter;
    private RottenTomatoesRestClient RTclient;

    public MovieSetSource()
    {

        var movieConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.moviesConnectionString);
        _movieSet = new DataSet();
        _movieAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Movie", movieConnection);
        RTclient = new RottenTomatoesRestClient("jcy6eyga8txee776kbn3mfe7");

        SqlCommandBuilder movieSQLBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(_movieAdapter);
        _movieAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
        _movieAdapter.Fill(_movieSet, "Movie");
    }

    public DataSet GetMovies()
    {
        return _movieSet;
    }

}
```

The Text property of the TextBox should update with the selectedItem from the listbox. It should also save edits after they are made in the textBox.

Comment: You mean a ListBox, don't you? Also what is the exact problem? No valid information appears?

Comment: Updated When i try updating the textbox it doesnt work

Comment: Thanks. But now it is a bit more confusing. I thought that you wanted to update movieListBox with the corresponding inputs from a textbox (for example "Name", linked to one of the columns of the DataSource). But now I am not sure what you want... what is nameText? The textbox? and what you want to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Updated again currently since in the movielistbox.SelectedItem its bound to a datatable, the selecteditem.name is the name of a movie but it wont update when you change the selection in a listbox

Comment: OK. I get what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code needs some tweaking. As far as I am not sure about the exact names in your datasource, here you have a small sample code (with fictitious values) showing how you should face this situation:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Country");

dt.Rows.Add("Name1", "Country1");
dt.Rows.Add("Name2", "Country2");

BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = dt;
movieListBox.DataSource = bindingSource;
movieListBox.ValueMember = "Name";

textBoxName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", movieListBox.DataSource, "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
textBoxCountry.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", movieListBox.DataSource, "Country", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Comment: Yeah see that's exactly what i already have. The problem is when I move in the listbox it doesn't update the textboxs

Comment: @Snowfiring No, this is not what you have. I have replaced movieListBox in your code with movieListBox.DataSource. Also the names you are using might be wrong. Test this code (create a new project and add the expected textboxes/listbox) and confirm that it works fine.

Comment: @Snowfiring note that my code refers directly to the DataSource of the ListBox ("Name" and Country" are the column names of the DataTable), not to the ListBox elements (what yours does). Just check that this code works fine (it would take you less than 1 minute) and adapt your code to this structure.